# How to get all records within the last Two Days from the current Date using EF 4?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

EF 4 in C#.

I have my query, at the moment I'm able to filter the result by the current Date (just date not considering TIME).

I need to filter the result **FROM the last two days TO the current Date** (no idea how to do it).

I tried in my query `currenteDate - 2` but without success.

Could you please give me an example? Thanks for your time on this.

```
DateTime currenteDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;

                var contents = from cnt in context.CmsContents
                               where cnt.IsPublished == true & cnt.IsDeleted == false & cnt.Date == currenteDate
                               orderby cnt.ContentId descending
                               select new { cnt.ContentId, cnt.Title, cnt.TitleUrl, cnt.Date, cnt.TypeContent };
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For changing current date you need use `currenteDate.AddDays(-2)`. And use `>=` instead of `==` to get all records from 2 days before and till the last record

```
DateTime currenteDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-2);

var contents = from cnt in context.CmsContents
                   where cnt.IsPublished == true & cnt.IsDeleted == false & cnt.Date >= currenteDate
                   orderby cnt.ContentId descending
                   select new { cnt.ContentId, cnt.Title, cnt.TitleUrl, cnt.Date, cnt.TypeContent };
```

Comment: sorry but I need all records FROM two days TO the currentDate, your code at a first look seems provide all the records of just two days ago. Am I correct?

Comment: I added comments to the answer. Check the latest code sample. I've changed the `==` to `>=`.

Comment: I get this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression .. any ideas?

Comment: Yes, prepeare value before expression `DateTime currenteDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-2);` and use as you used before, just `currenteDate `

Answer (score 0):

use the compare method from the DateTime-object:

```
cnt.Date.CompareTo( DateTime.Now.AddDays( -2 ) ) >= 0
```

Comment: ERROR: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)'

Comment: do you use DateTime.Now.AddDays( -2 ) (RIGHT!) or just simply DateTime.AddDays( -2 ) (WRONG!) ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [other SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146300/lnq-to-ef-datetime-problem) `EntityFunctions.AddDays(p.StartDate, p.Period)` ... Seems so there is a special function in the EF for this problem.