# QueryExtender Linq Orderby using TimeSpan.Parse

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, query-extender

Basically I have a QueryExtender control of ASP.NET and 
First I need to Convert sql varchar value to TimeSpan of CSharp type then apply Linq OrderBy Clause on it, but get an error when execute.

Here is my code:

```
  protected void FilterProducts(object sender, CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Query = (from p in e.Query.Cast<accounts>()
                  select p).OrderBy(p=> TimeSpan.Parse(p.TimeTo));
    }
```

ERROR:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What does `p.TimeTo` look like? Can't you just order by the string?

Comment: 1. You could maybe use SqlFunctions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466176.aspx ). But could you show examples of TimeTo ? 2. If TimeTo represents Time values, why is it a Varchar in DB ?

Comment: p.TimeTo is varchar type in sql server like: 1:00

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus basically i m using sql server 2005 and u know that Time type is not available in this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing all about the shape of your `p.TimeTo` data I think you can use the string value to order by, this way:

```
from p in e.Query.Cast<accounts>()
select p).OrderBy(p => p.TimeTo.Length).ThenBy(p => p.TimeTo)
```

This way, a value `1:00` will be sorted before `11:00`.

**EDIT**

Take:

```
var s = new[] { "12:10", "8:00", "8:20",  "1:00", "1:02", "10:00", "11:10" };
```

And see the difference between

```
s.OrderBy (x => x);
```

and

```
s.OrderBy (x => x.Length).ThenBy (x => x);
```

Which is:

> 1:00
>   1:02
>   10:00
>   11:10
>   12:10
>   8:00
>   8:20

and

> 1:00
>   1:02
>   8:00
>   8:20
>   10:00
>   11:10
>   12:10

Comment: I have 1:00 to 24:00 in the field.

Comment: i think not because you know that 11:00 and 10:00 have the same length so how we ensure that 10:00 come first????

Comment: GREAT WORK GERT ARNOLD :) ACCEPTED

Answer (score 1):

That is because `TimeSpan.Parse` is not available on the store, your query gets translated into SQL if you are using SQLServer, and that store doesn't have `TimeSpan.Parse`, one approach would be convert it to a list and then query again.

```
e.Query = (from p in e.Query.Cast<accounts>()
           select p).ToList().OrderBy(p=> TimeSpan.Parse(p.TimeTo));
```

But the above solution may cause some problem if `ToList` returns huge set of data.

Comment: You may see this thread as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146300/linq-to-entityframework-datetime

Comment: This is a dangerous work-around, what happens if ToList() return a huge amount of data?

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanSaleem, didn't you see the last line on my answer ? I already said that. This is the problem with this approach. Its upto you

Comment: Thanks Habib, but is there any other workaround?? or wait for the next release of linq and entity framework? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16016/discussion-between-muhammad-adnan-saleem-and-habib)

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanSaleem, its not there in LINQ and I don't think it can be there in future versions, because its hard to implement, The best approach would be to use `Time` data type in SQL server rather than varchar