# How to use DATEADD over column in LINQ - DateAdd is not recognized by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to invalidate requests of friendship that were reponded less than 30 days ago.

```
var requestIgnored = context.Request
    .Where(c => c.IdRequest == result.IdRequest 
             && c.IdRequestTypes == 1 
             && c.Accepted == false 
             && DateTime.Now <= (((DateTime)c.DateResponse).AddDays(30)))
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

`c.DateResponse` is of type `DateTime?`. The error I am having is :

> LINQ does not recognize the command .AddDays

Comment: What LinqProvider are you using? For L2E: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146300/linq-to-entityframework-datetime

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Edit:** If you're using EntityFramework >= 6.0, use [`DbFunctions.AddDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.adddays). For older versions of Entity Framework, use [`EntityFunctions.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412479.aspx):

```
var requestIgnored = context.Request
    .Where(c => c.IdRequest == result.IdRequest 
             && c.IdRequestTypes == 1 
             && c.Accepted == false 
             && DateTime.Now <= DbFunctions.AddDays(c.DateResponse, 30))
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: EntityFunctions is a new world for me !! thank you!! This worked really good.

Comment: You should then "accept as answer". Cross the checkmark next to the answer. This will give credit to the person who helped you and help others quickly locate the correct answer.

Comment: Note that `EntityFunctions` will only work inside an EF context. Attempting to evaluate the method (i.e. on a local collection for unit tests) will throw an exception.

Comment: Just found this post and implemented the above code, to be instructed that System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions is now obsolete, and is replaced by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.

Comment: Thanks @BrettRigby, I've updated the answer for EF 6

Comment: Please note: Unfortuantely EFCore 1.1 (which used to be EF7) does not yet have this functionality. This can result in horribly inefficient SQL where logic is being ran in C# that you would have expected to run in the DB : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2850

Comment: Both of those links go to the same place.

Answer (score 6):

You might try this:

```
var thirtyDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
var requestIgnored = context.Request
    .Where(c => 
        c.IdRequest == result.IdRequest && 
        c.IdRequestTypes == 1 && 
        c.Accepted == false && 
        c.DateResponse.HasValue &&
        thirtyDaysAgo <= c.DateResponse.Value)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```