# Compare two sql dates using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql

I need to compare two dates that are on SQLServer, to see if the user has already logged after 10 seconds of his register on the system, but when I try this query, it gives me a

```
NotSupportedException [System.NotSupportedException] = {"System.DateTime AddSeconds(Double)"}
```

Query:

```
var query = from user in this.Query()
            where (user.LastLoginDate.AddSeconds(-10) <= user.CreateDate) 
            select std;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use DATEADD over column in LINQ - DateAdd is not recognized by LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371798/how-to-use-dateadd-over-column-in-linq-dateadd-is-not-recognized-by-linq)

Comment: Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities?

Comment: the problem is that I'm comparing two SQLDates.

It is linq-to-sql

Comment: This is a non-issue. In LINQ-to-SQL it's supported. It's not clear if OP have their tags right and below the accepted answer there is a vague comment "I managed to change the requirements". Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is really dirty (and probably bad perfomance if you don't have indexes) way to solve your problem but it should work:

```
var query = from user in this.Query()
            where ((user.LastLoginDate.Date == user.CreateDate.Date
                && user.LastLoginDate.Hour == user.CreateDate.Hour
                && user.LastLoginDate.Minute == user.CreateDate.Minute
                && user.LastLoginDate.Second <= user.CreateDate.Second + 10)
                ||(user.LastLoginDate.Date == user.CreateDate.Date
                && user.LastLoginDate.Hour == user.CreateDate.Hour
                && user.LastLoginDate.Minute + 1 == user.CreateDate.Minute
                && 60 - user.CreateDate.Second + user.LastLoginDate.Second <= 10)) 
            select std;
```

I think you get the idea.

Comment: can you say, does it help you?

Comment: Yea, that woud work, but it's complex, but I managed to change the requirements, thanks