# Return last 10 days data by date using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to return last 10 days list using Entity Framework by date. `DateSigned` is my `date` column. I already tried the code shown below, but this does not return the last 10 days of data, this returns 10 days back data. How can I fix it?

```
var Chart = dbcontext.CampaignEmails
                     .Where(x => x.DateSigned > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DATEADD over column in LINQ - DateAdd is not recognized by LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371798/how-to-use-dateadd-over-column-in-linq-dateadd-is-not-recognized-by-linq)

Comment: he's not saying he has a runtime error...its not a duplicate

Comment: Can u answer how can i implement solution on my case?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't working? It should work. Maybe you need to save the calculated date in a variable first, but then you would get an exception anyway...

Comment: This returns me 10 days back data only not 10 days to today date

Comment: @johnCogdle can you let us know what value does the DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) return? I suspect you either have incorrect system date or some timezon thing is causing it not to work.

Comment: @johnCogdle for "10 days to today's date" You must include `>=` sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tenDaysAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
var Chart = dbcontext.CampaignEmails.Where(x => x.DateSigned >= tenDaysAgo).ToList();
```

Is what you are looking for i guess.
If you only want 10 records you can use [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) LINQ method before the ToList() call.
Furthermore, you may need to order your results before even accessing them with a [OrderBy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx).