# Complex DateTime query in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I would like to ask how to write a complex DateTime query in Entity Framework as below:

I have this code in service:

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime> calculate24HoursLater = (date) =>
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        return date.AddDays(3);

    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        return date.AddDays(3).Date;

    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        return date.AddDays(2).Date;

    return date.AddDays(1);
};

var unactionedEnquiries = 
    dataContext.ContactedBrokerEnquiries
        .Include("ContactedBrokers")
        .Where(
            x => x.ContactedBrokers.All(c => c.Status == (byte)LeadStatus.Rejected) || 
                x.ContactedBrokers.Any(c => c.Status == (byte)LeadStatus.New && calculate24HoursLater(c.CreatedDate) < DateTime.Now)
        ).OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate);
```

The result `unactionedEnquiries`, I expect it should be IQueryable. It means SQL server does not execute until my next statement

However, I get exception on `calculate24HoursLater(c.CreatedDate) < DateTime.Now)`
This statment cannot translate into SQL statement. I know the reason but I dont know how to write that `rule` in `Entity Framework` query

Important: I dont prefer to push all of data into RAM then filter with that condition. Ideally, it should be in `SQL-Server`

Could you please let me know how to write them in SQL-EF statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146300/linq-to-entityframework-datetime) @andrew's genius answer, you can do:

```
var calcDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);

var unactionedEnquiries = 
    dataContext.ContactedBrokerEnquiries
        .Include("ContactedBrokers")
        .Where(
            x => x.ContactedBrokers.All(c => c.Status == (byte)LeadStatus.Rejected) || 
                x.ContactedBrokers.Any(c => c.Status == (byte)LeadStatus.New && c.CreatedDate < calcDate)
        ).OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate);
```

Comment: it's really genius answer, awesome ^_^

Comment: Well, in this code I don't see how you can use a reference date that depends on day number.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at possibly using the [SQLFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) Methods that are available for doing date operations in LINQ queries

**Sample (Untested)**  Try replacing your Func definition with the following:

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime> calculate24HoursLater = (date) =>
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        return SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 3, date).Value;

    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        return SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 3, date).Value;

    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        return SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 2, date).Value;

    return SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 1, date).Value;
};
```

Comment: SQLFunctions is for use with LINQ to EF, not sure why the down vote??

Comment: Yes, but your `Func` doesn't.